# How to fix this code for splash-screen?

Tags: java

I am trying to make splash-screen for a game, both of which are JFrames. I want the splash-screen to open for 3 seconds, then be disposed of. The JFrame for the main part of the game needs to be created and shown immediately afterwards. I am using Thread.sleep() to wait for 3 seconds but the loading page is delayed 3 seconds instead of the game. Code is below:

```
new load();
try 
{
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    dispose();
    new gameInfo();
} 
catch (InterruptedException ex) 
{
    Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: We need a bit more context. What exactly does `dispose` do, and what are the side effects of constructing `load` and `gameInfo` objects?

Comment: Why not use SplashScreen of Java? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to run it on new thread because what you did for now is freezing the main thread and it's affecting the GUI and make it freeze too. So, you need to wait for 3000ms in the background, and the only simply way is make a new thread. here's is the pseudocode

```
new load();
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            //i think you should call this 2 lines below in main thread
            dispose();
            new gameInfo();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }       
    }
}.start();
```

this code not going to work, this is just the pseudocode. i need to see the whole class to make it able to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
new load();
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            //i think you should call this 2 lines below in main thread
            dispose();
            new gameInfo();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }       
    }
}.start();
```